# Parse Cloud Code Before Save on saveAll Batches from Client

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im trying to figure out the best way to handle incoming saveAll batches from our iOS client.  A user can create a few comments in the app and if they leave the app or move away from the comment page it does a batch save of all the comment objects.

In cloud code I need to check the support ticket count for an organization that the comment is associated with, then increment the count on the org object, and save the comment with the ticket number.

So lets say when 2 comments are saved, it gets the ticket number but saves both comments with the same ticket number.

ex: org ticket count 100
2 comments are added from our client with saveAll function.

Cloud code is supposed to get the org ticket count, then save the comment with the ticket count, increment the org ticket count and save the next etc.

here is some example code im playing around with.. everything works but the comments from saveAll are all saved with the same org ticket number.

```
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Comment", function(request, response) {
// when a comment is added we get the current ticketNumber value
// from the org, and assign it to the new comment.
// after that we increment the counter on the org.

console.log('========================')
console.log(request.object.id) // empty
console.log(request.object.get('org'))
console.log('========================')

var orgId = request.object.get("org").id
// get the count from the org
query = new Parse.Query('Organization')
query.equalTo("objectId", orgId)
query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(object) {
    console.log('in query')
    // assign it as a variable.
    var ticketNumber = object.get('ticketNumber')
    console.log(ticketNumber)
    // atomic increment ticket number on org
    object.increment("ticketNumber")
    object.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    // save the ticketNumber to the comment
    request.object.set("ticketNumber", ticketNumber)
    response.success();      
  }, function(error) {
    response.error("something happened")
  });

});
```

of course this works if one object comes in.. its just when multiple objects are saved from the client..

Comment: ticketNumber is a int in the org collection.. so lets say it starts at 100.. org (some other data) ticket number = 100.  A comment comes in, we check what the latest ticket number is on the org in this case it would be 100, we then assign 100 to the comment ticket number.. its more for support stuff internally..

Comment: the iOS client uses PFObject saveAllInBackground:block , so if someone submitted 3 comments, when they exit the app this function gets called and all 3 objects are saved to the db.  When they hit cloud code the request block has 3 objects, but request.object.set("ticketNumber", ticketNumber) saves the same number each time.. im not sure how to loop over this or how to handle 3 objects .. if someone saves one comment, aka one object is returned then it works

Comment: so, if 3 comments are saved with saveAll, and cloud code gets that data, i would expect the beforeSave to be hit 3 times.. then I get the ticket number from the org, assign it to comments, increment the ticket number on the org, then do the same for the next object.. im not sure why its not working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving and querying for the `Org` is going to happen asynchronously, and all your saves are going to happen at the same time, fetching that same org, and assigning the old value before any of the saves go through.

Instead of saveAll from the iOS client, create a cloud code function that takes an array of comments to save. If they all belong to the same Org, you can fetch that once from the first comment, and then iterate through your comments, incrementing the org's ticketNumber and assigning it to each object in turn, then save everything (comments and org) together.

If the comments aren't always the same org, you could first iterate through your comments to get all orgs you need, stick them in an array and do a fetchAll, then iterate through your comments and access the orgs appropriately.  This is a good idea so you're fetching two objects once each instead of two objects 10 times each in the case you have 20 tickets, 10 each for 2 different orgs.

If you still need access to the tickets, you can save the org and tickets separately, and return the save result of saveAll on the comments.

Edit:

In cloud code, you could have something like this, assuming all Comments have the same org:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveComments", function(request, response) {
    var comments = request.params.comments;
    if( !comments || comments.length == 0 ) return response.success(); //Handle case with no comments to save - Job done!
    var org = comments[0].get("org");
    // Since you don't need to include any Parse Objects, you can use fetch instead of query
    org.fetch({useMasterKey:true}).then(
        function(organization) {
            for( comment in comments ) {
                organization.increment("ticketNumber");
                comment.set("ticketNumber", organization.get("ticketNumber"));
            }
            return organization.save(null, {useMasterKey:true}).then(
                function(organization) {
                    return Parse.Object.saveAll(comments, {useMasterKey:true}); //Put this after saving the org, so the return value is the same as your current client save all call
                }
            );
        }
    ).then(
        function(success) { response.success(success); },
        function(error) { response.error(error); }
    );
});
```

Then on your iOS client, instead of using saveAll, you would do something like so:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{"comments":commentsArray};
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"saveComments" withParams:params...];`
```

Comment: Hmm, Ok ill have to see how to handle this.. I thought I was running into a async issue, I can get the client to save each comments as a separate save since its not a huge issue for us, we just like to keep things in batches when possible.  As far as the cloud code function that takes an array of comments to save, im not 100% sure what your saying.. btw thanks for the reply.

Comment: When you save in batches, are all comments going to have the same org value?

Comment: I added an example of how you'd use a cloud code function for this instead of client saveAll. It assumes `commentsArray` is the same array you'd use in your `saveAll` call, and that all comments have the same `org` value. You'll have to tweak it as appropriate for your use.

Comment: I had a typo in the if condition checking to make sure there was at least one comment - was trying to check for an empty array but forgot to compare length to 0.  In case you had tried using that code and were not getting any results.